# Multiple image input tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have problem with data preparation with Tensorflow:
This is my code

```
class Data:
    data = []
    init = False
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
    #initize
    def __init__(self, path, img_size = (640, 640)):
        all_file = os.listdir(path) #take all couple files
        #load couple images
        data1 = []
        data2 = []
        label = []
        for i in all_file:
            #take couple path
            if platform.system() == 'Darwin' and i.startswith('.'):
                continue
            temp_path = os.listdir(path + '/' + i)
            temp_path.pop(temp_path.index('label.txt'))
            f = open(path +'/' + i + '/label.txt', "r")
            label.append(int(f.read()))
            data1.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path +'/' + i + '/' + temp_path[0]),img_size))
            data2.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path +'/' + i + '/' + temp_path[1]),img_size))
            
        self.data = np.array([data1, data2])
        self.label = np.array(label)
        self.init = True

    def load_data_generator(self, b_size):
        if not self.init :
            raise Exception('Data need to be initialized first')
        # print(np.shape(self.data))
        # generator = self.datagen.flow(x = part_data,y = part_label, batch_size=8)
        
        genX1 = self.datagen.flow(x = self.data[0],
                                  y = self.label,
                                batch_size = b_size,
                                shuffle=False, 
                                seed=7)
    
        genX2 = self.datagen.flow(x = self.data[1],
                                  y = self.label,
                                batch_size = b_size,
                                shuffle=False, 
                                seed=7)
        while True:
            X1i = genX1.next()
            X2i = genX2.next()
            yield (X1i[0], X2i[0]), X2i[1]
        

data = Data('/Users/admin/Desktop/Long journey/Research/Test')
#Test model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet101
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
import tensorflow as tf

resnet_1 = ResNet101(input_shape = (320, 320, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)
resnet_2 = ResNet101(input_shape = (320, 320, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)
x = resnet_1.layers[-2].output
y = resnet_2.layers[-2].output
#fix duplicate name
for layer in resnet_1.layers :
    layer._name = layer.name + str('_1')
for layer in resnet_2.layers :
    layer._name = layer.name + str('_2')
# combine the output of the two branches
combined = concatenate([x, y])
# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the
# combined outputs
z = Dense(4096, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z)
# our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
# then output a single value
model = Model(inputs=[resnet_1.input, resnet_2.input], outputs=z)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer='adam')

tmp = next(data.load_data_generator(8))
print(np.shape(a))
print(np.shape(b))
model.fit_generator(tmp,
                    epochs=2)
```

And I recieve error like this:

(2, 8, 640, 640, 3)
(8,)
/Users/admin/Desktop/Long journey/Research/Model/Data/input.py:98: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
model.fit_generator(tmp,
Epoch 1/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Long journey/Research/Model/Data/input.py", line 98, in 
model.fit_generator(tmp,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2810, in fit_generator
return self.fit(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/var/folders/x6/4mrrj52939970dsbyznz2qwr0000gn/T/**autograph_generated_filet8blb8l9.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
retval* = ag*_.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1080, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 219, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 640, 640, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 640, 640, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>]
```

I don't have experience with config double input in tensorflow, what should I do?
I hope I can recieve a sample project or advice for this thing, I am stucking in this think too long